# Laravel homestead and dependencies

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I successfully dropped a column in my database without having to explicitly add doctrine/dbal dependency, even though the docs says one should.
I am using Laravel Homestead. I want to know if Laravel homestead adds all dependencies automatically.

Comment: Are you referring to [this part of the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#dropping-columns)? The sentence about `doctrine/dbal` is about SQLite exclusively, maybe you are using some other DB?

Comment: Oh!, I didn't notice the SQLite when going through the docs. I'm using Mysql.